# type3-only lexers in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I'm thinking about using ANTLR in my lecture on formal languages since it's input language is pretty clean and easy to learn. 
Since I am not an expert using ANTLR I tried some standard examples to get familiar with it's syntax, error messages etc.
Doing so I found out, that:

```
lexer grammar KFG;
R  : 'a'R'b' | 'ab';
```

is a valid lexer that can be executed e.g. by:

```
echo "aaabbb" | grun KFG tokens -tokens
```

Since the grammar is context free it should only be parsable by a parser an not a lexer.

Is there any way to force ANTLR to accept only type 3 grammars for lexers?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to force ANTLR to accept only type 3 grammars for lexers?

AFAIK, no, that is not possible.